# Does type always stored in memory using its size?

Tags: c++, types, ram

Is it safe to say that variables of primitive types like: ‘char’, ‘short’, ‘int’, ‘long’, and ‘long long’ would be always stored in RAM using its size?

For example ‘long long’ will be stored using 8 bytes even if it value is equal to 15.

Comment: yes, all types have a specific size at compile time regardless of their value. However, classes may allocate additional memory from the free store (heap) based on value, like `std::vector` or `std::string`

Comment: RAM is a specific type of memory which is generally managed by the operating system. So, just a minor nit that your program's memory can be a fixed size, but the actual RAM used may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes because C++ and C do actually expose the memory representation of (some) values and you can even use `memcpy` to copy the bytes of a variable in or out safely with certain types (POD "plain old data" types).

No because the compiler is given quite a bit of freedom in what to do exactly with the generated code and for example in a function like:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

most probably `c` with any decent compiler will not be given any RAM location at all and will just exist temporarily in CPU registers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to say a variable is stored as its data type size. The reason is if it is stored on the basis of its value then the variable whose value is not assigned will never exist(which is false-variables without value exist with some garbage value).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to say that variables of primitive types like: `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long` would be always stored in RAM using its size?

### In theory, a RAM is not required by C++.

Since C++11 is a *specification* written in English (in [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)), and that  standard does not even mention RAM. My understanding of C++11 is that a C++ implementation could (in principle) run on mechanical computers like an hypothetical scaled up variant of [Babbage Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine), and such a computer don't have any [DRAM module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_module).

In practice, most processors would hold a variable in RAM, but notice that the [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) or the [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) of a motherboard (e.g. some [Asus ROG STRIX TRX40-E](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-Strix-TRX40-E-Gaming/) for example) is probably written mostly in C or C++ and can run *without* DRAM modules (using only the processor [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)). Look also into [coreboot](https://www.coreboot.org/).

Most [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), invoked [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -O3`) would try hard to hold [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) in [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register).

> For example `long long` will be stored using 8 bytes even if it value is equal to 15.

Very probably yes, but you then should use the standard [`std::int64_t` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

At last, most C++ programs run under the control of some [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) with [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) support, and at some times a variable is not even inside RAM (just in the swap area of some disk).